# Samsung Galaxy A3

Tags: contacts, samsung, vcard

Can someone help me please. I imported a vcf card into my Samsung which asks if I want to save it to my contacts. I say yes, I have even selected edit and then done, I have set my contacts to view all and checked each option, but the imported contact is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Hi, even when I select display contacts in Sim card,  or device or all the contact is not in any of the contact lists.

Answer (score 0):

You might have imported contacts to your sim card, In that case you need to import it to phone contacts from SIM card or you can reimport the contacts from vcf to your phone memory.